# Chrome selected text color no longer works with CSS custom property (variable)

Tags: css, google-chrome

This used to work, but now this code no longer works, not sure what happened.
I have a theme with various colors set by CSS custom props. I use the theme to set the color of text when it is selected. I am using Chrome With Chrome Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (64-bit), on Ubuntu 22.04, x-server with i3 window manager, Nvidia graphics.

```css
:root {
    --selection-color: green;
}
::selection {
    color: white;
    background: var(--selection-color, red);
}
```

```html
<p>Some text to select with your cursor<br> It should be green if the custom prop is working correctly, red if not</p>
```

The selected text is supposed to be green.

Comment: Chrome 114 does not show the issue...

Comment: The snippet demo works correctly for me. Strangely, looking at it in Developer Tools, it says "--selection-color is not defined" and shows the background color is red. If I declare the variable for the pseudo-element, Developer Tools shows the expected result. I'd chalk this oddity up to a Developer Tools error but don't know why it isn't working for you.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I just updated to Chrome 114, but still see the issue. Using Ubuntu.

Comment: Tested with Version 114.0.5735.199 (Official Build) (64-bit) and this seems to work just fine.  Something NOT in the question might be in play here.

Comment: Even in guest mode  (with no extensions) it is red to me (With Chrome Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: Please provide more information that helps us to reproduce your issue. Which Ubuntu version do you use, which display manager. Do you have the same issue if you use Firefox etc. ... Please add new information not only as comment but to your original question. Use tags to attract people that may have the requested knowledge.

Comment: @Markus Just to verify, you are saying that even the runnable snippet demo in this question is showing red in your browser?

Comment: @TimR: In my browser the selected text is underlayed in green as supposed. So I can't reproduce the issue. That is why I asked run_the_race to add more information that may help to reproduce the issue. Screenshots of the observed behaviour might be helpful, too. Are you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Markus Sorry, somehow I tagged the wrong person. My intention was to tag the OP, run_the_race -- Just to verify, you are saying that even the runnable snippet demo that you provided in your question is showing red in your browser?

Comment: FYI -- Green in the current versions of Firefox and Opera.

Comment: Works for me even with the *ancient* Chrome 59.

Comment: What about using `background-color` than `background`? What about limiting the scope of your variable like `::selection {--selection-color: green; background: var(--selection-color, red);}`. Just add more information if you want people to help you

Comment: Do you have [Experimental Web Platform features enabled?](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50295)

Comment: @Markus Ubuntu 22.04, using xserver, with nvidia graphics

Comment: @Krokomot, works on firefox for me too, I think it is a chrome bug.

Comment: I am running on `114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)` and have almost the same problem. It occurs when using `color-mix` on `border-color` with a `var()` expression inside `color-mix`. `color-mix` in general works, but the combination of all does not. Upgrading Chromium to 118 fixed it; so it was a Chromium Bug in my case

Comment: I think the reason is that Pseudo elements dont inherit custom props (althought they used to). I cannot fathom why. That makes it impossible to apply theme colors to things like `::backdrop` and `::selection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have was due to a change to the CSS inheritance for ::selection enabled in Chrome on and off for the last several versions. It has been on consistently for user that have "Experimental Web Platform features" enabled in chrome://flags.

The specific change causes all highlight pseudos, including selection, to inherit through the highlight chain instead of from their originating element. This meant, for a time, that custom properties on :root were not inherited by ::selection because the root for ::selection is :root::selection.

This specific use case has been fixed by having :root::selection inherit custom properties from :root. So your case should be working since about Chrome 120.

The ongoing problem is in cases where specific elements re-define the custom property to control selection for that element and its descendants. This use case will be broken when the inheritance changes are enabled, and you should instead define a blah::selection for the element that you wish to have a different style.

Comment: To update, the change in Chrome is not likely to become permanent until we find a way to support the previous method of using custom property inheritance for coloring selection, and even then possibly not until other browsers implement the changes.

Answer (score -2):

You please try with this

```css
:root {
  --selection-color: green;
}

::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}

p::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: var(--selection-color, red);
  opacity: 0.3;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

p::selection {
  background-color: var(--selection-color, red);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me, the selected text is still red.